# REST API - Update relationship between entities

Tags: rest, updates, entity-relationship

This is how you add a book to a author in my API:

```
PUT /authors/1/books/1/
```

I now want to change the book to another author.

How can I do that? I am thinking in the following options.

1- Making /authors and /books both top-level resources. Control what author a book is on using a property on the book, for example `authorId: 2`. For example, `PUT /book/1` and set `authorId: 2` in the body with other attributes.

2 - Perform `PUT /authors/2/books/1/`, changing the existing author's book to 2. With this method I should check if the book already exists. If exists I update the author and the other attributes, if not I would create a new book.

Which would be the best option in term of best practices? Is the second option a nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are uniquely identifiable therefore both should be resources in their own right i.e.

```
GET /authors/1
GET /books/1
```

Therefore the second option you suggest IMO seems the most sensible i.e.

```
PUT /books/1

{ authorId: 2 }
```

Comment: You mean the first option, right? :) I prefer this way too. Is this the way it is usually done or are there better ways?

Comment: @Mr.Mars whoops, yes, the first scenario you proposed. Depends on what your definition of "better" is, to me, this approach is the "best" way of doing what you want given your setup, and for a typical PUT would be a very popular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me assume something..

- one book one author
- you already have book's id, because it goes first in your statement, right
- you already have author's id you want to set

Then, let me impose something..

```
POST /books/1
{
  op: 'set'
  entity: 'authorId'
  value: 2
}
```

(I'm not saying that's the best practice, just an example)

Answer (score 1):

The URI is an identifier - from the perspective of general-purpose components it is semantically opaque.  Information about the current state of the resource is expressed in the representation, not in the identifier.

> I now want to change the book to another author.

As a client, the usual way to do this would be to download a copy of the representation of the book, modify your local copy to reference the new author, and then issuing a PUT request to the same target-uri that you used to GET the representation.  The PUT semantics ask the server to change the server's representation of the target resource to match the client's.

The server can encode information into the URI, but that information is exclusively for the use of the server.

Which, yes, means that potentially the client may make edits to the representation that conflict with the "semantics" expressed in the URI.  This is analogous to a situation where a filename and its contents aren't aligned.

The server, having understood the semantics of the general purpose request, can then decide what to do about it.  Reasonable options would include

- Rejecting the request
- Accepting the edits in place, leaving the disagreement between the identifier and the representation
- Accepting those edits in some other place, effectively creating (or editing) a new resource.

The last option is probably the trickiest to get right, in terms of getting a general purpose client to match its understanding to the server's updated resource model.